# How to create alert in elastalert, where count(anything) yesterday is > or < today count(anything)

Tags: alert, elastalert

Tried creating alerts in Elastalert in an aggregated way.
Like,
Create an alert in elastalert, where count(anything) yesterday is > or < today count(anything).

This is not happening. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of rule/aggregation type are you using?
Can you please share the ES query/result if possible here?

You can create your own result processor as a python module and decide whether to create an alert or not as shared in the below link.
https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/adding_enhancements.html